# undefined columns selected and cannot xtfrm data frame error

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

I am trying to write a code that checks for outliers based on IQR and change those respective values to "NA". So I wrote this:

```
dt <- rnorm(200) 
dg <- rnorm(200)
dh <- rnorm(200)

l <- c(1,3) #List of relevant columns

df <- data.frame(dt,dg,dh)
```

To check if the column contains any outliers and change their value to NA:

```
vector.is.empty <- function(x) return(length(x) ==0) 
#Checks for empty values in vector and returns booleans. 

for (i in 1:length(l)){
 IDX <- l[i]
 BP <- boxplot.stats(df[IDX])
 OutIDX <- which(df[IDX] %in% BP$out)
 if (vector.is.empty(OutIDX)==FALSE){
  for (u in 1:length(OutIDX)){
      IDX2 <- OutIDX[u]
      df[IDX2,IDX] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I run this code, I get these error messages:

[image]

I've tried to search online for any good answers. but I'm not sure why they claim that the column is unspecified. Any clues here?

Comment: Your `df` contains only two columns, while you are calling two the first and third columns, using `l <- c(1,3)`

Comment: Oh that was my bad. It was supposed to contain all columns. This is just a reproducible code, so the real code doesn't have that issue. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like that in order to replace the outliers:

```
# Set a seed (to make the example reproducible)
  set.seed(31415)
# Generate the data.frame
  df <- data.frame(dt = rnorm(100), dg = rnorm(100), dh = rnorm(100))
# A list to save the result of boxplot.stats()
  l <- list()
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    l[[i]] <- boxplot.stats(df[,i])
    df[which(df[,i]==l[[i]]$out),i] <- NA
  }

# Which values have been replaced?
  lapply(l, function(x) x$out)
```